# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument - Se corrompe el tercer intento

Tags: python, scraping, beautifulsoup, google-drive

Estoy armando un código que descarga de forma automática una serie de archivos (todos **xls** de la misma fuente) y reescribe los preexistentes que están ubicados en un drive.

Estoy usando este código:

```py
remote_url = 'http://www.webconarchivo.com/archivo.xls'
local_file = "G:\Mi unidad\Carpeta_1\Carpeta_2\archivo.xls"
request.urlretrieve(remote_url, local_file)
```

Y lo repito para cada uno de los archivos. Los primeros dos funcionan perfecto, pero el tercero me da *OSError*:

> [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'G:\Mi unidad\Carpeta_1\Carpeta_2\x0cin2021.xls'.

`x0cin2021` no es el nombre del archivo y la ubicación en el script es la correcta.

¿Alguna idea de qué puede ser?

Comment: cuál es el nombre del archivo??

Comment: En el código que copie lo puse como "archivo.xls" para simplificar pero el nombre real es "fin2021"

Comment: pues al parecer te está convirtiendo la `f` en su representación hexadecimal que sería `0xc` y eso causa el error de argumento inválido

Comment: Tiene sentido, no me había dado cuenta, gracias! Alguna idea de por qué hace eso o como solucionarlo? Lo único que encuentro googleando es como convertir un int a hex

Comment: pues seguro es por que está escapando el caracter `f` al hacer `\f` para evitar esto coloca una doble barra `\\ ` o la otra barra en su lugar `/`

Comment: Funcionó! Un millón de gracias :)